# Multiple popup for codesign wants to access key "access" in your keychain

Tags: xcode, keychain

After build my app, I got error with codesign wants to access key "access" in your keychain and multiple popup as shown in screenshot attached:

[image]

I would like to ask how to fix this error? After entering all the password didn't solve the issue. Clicking "Always Allow" didn't solve the issue either. Many thanks.

Comment: Yes I did reboot the computer and clear the caches. Didn't work. thanks

Comment: One more idea. Have you tried actually going to Keychain Access and unlocking the login keychain?

Comment: That is the scariest screenshot I have ever seen. God bless your soul.

Comment: Changing the target device or restarting the Xcode works for me

Comment: I tried restart, deleting and changing permissions on keys and certs. I tried deleting all pods as well as updating xcode. The accepted answer is the only thing that worked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to allow `codesign` in the access list:

`security set-key-partition-list -S apple-tool:,apple:,codesign: -s -k keychainPass`

Comment: Just tried and it works! Thanks a lot for the answer and solve my pain point.

Comment: Should I write "keychainPass" verbatim? That did not work and also replacing it with my login password which is also the password for the login keychain did not work:

    security set-key-partition-list -S apple-tool:,apple:,codesign: -s -k my password

.... leads to this Result:

    security: SecKeychainUnlock: The user name or passphrase you entered is not correct.

Comment: I did not enter any username, do not even know how I could do that

Comment: entering my login keychain password worked for me - Thanks!

Comment: you saved me a lot of time! thanks mate

Comment: *NOTE* you do not need the "-k" flag, you should omit it, if you omit it you'll be prompted for your password and dont need to type if clear text (into you shell history etc).

Answer (score 4):

Enter your password and then Click on Always Allow. That did the job for me.

Comment: Just tried it, clicking on "Always Allow"  instead of "Allow" works. thanks

Comment: This has been spammed everywhere and doesn't work. The accepted answer works - trying to create more visibility for it.